# How to call and pipe multiple postgres commands from python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, command-line, pipe

In order to *copy* a file-like object to a *postgres* database, I take the following steps:

```
~$ sudo psql -U postgres
password for root: 
password for user postgres:
postgres=# \c migration v0
You are now connected to database "migration_v0" as user "postgres".
migration_v0=# cat file.csv | \copy table1 from stdin csv
```

I want to take the exact same steps, but from within *Python* and want to pass a `StringIO` buffer instead of a literal file. My first attempt consisted of the following steps:

```
# test.py

fmt = r"copy table1 FROM stdin csv"
sql = fmt.format(string_io)
psql = ['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-c', sql]
output = subprocess.check_output(psql)
print(output)
```

The command is executed (a prompt pops up to type the password for the user *postgres*) but I get the following error:

> ERROR:  relation "table1" does not exist

This happens because I am currently trying to execute `\copy` on the default database `postgres` instead of `migration_v0`. Thus, I want to include both commands in the subprocess call (`\c migration_v0` and `\copy ...`) and I don't know how to do this, since the postgres' flag `-c` takes only a single command.

I looked up a workaround and came across with this command line example:

```
\c migration_v0 \\ \copy ... | psql -U postgres
```

, but I have no idea how I can port this to python code.

Any suggestions on how I can pull this off?

#### Edit 1

I realized the flag `-d` also enables switching databases so now I don't need to run multiple commands. My code now looks like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([
                         'psql', '-U', 'postgres', 
                         '-d', 'migration_v0', 
                         '-c', '\copy table1 FROM stdin csv'], 
                      shell=False, 
                      stdin=string_io)
```

but I get the following error:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Apparently `StringIO` doesn't implement `fileno`. At this point I'm wondering if it's even possible to achieve what I want to through a subprocess call.

Comment: Just change psql to ['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-c', sql, '-d', 'migration_v0'].  It might be better to just use psycopg2 with copy_from, though.

Comment: I just realized I can use `-d` as well, so my original problem is solved. The issue is `StringIO` doesn't implement `fileno` so I'm guessing there is no chance to use it as input in a command line

Comment: You should set stdin=subprocess.PIPE and then use p.stdin.write to enter the contents of the string_io.  Still, I think it's better to just use psycopg2.

Comment: @Jeremy It seems doing that process row by row is costly, performance wise. I am actually trying `psycopg` but I'm stuck right now regarding a `.read() call error`. I posted a similar question some time ago, to which you responded. I made a new one here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650538/copy-from-throws-read-call-error-on-bulk-data-on-psycopg2)

Comment: Ah, right, sorry.  You shouldn't have to read your stringIO line by line, though.  You should be able to just dump in the whole thing.

Comment: Oh I will look into it, I saw an example from the docs where they insert each row individually so I thought that'd be the only way